# Login redirect using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, authentication, redirect

i'll be glad if anyone can help out am working on a login system using jquery but i encounter a problem

what i want to achieve is user filling out their details on the login page and i'll process it using jQuery at the back end without reloading the page, i have achive that but the problem now is when the details they provide and the details in the database is correct i want to redirect them to another page

**here is my login form**

```
<form class="form-login" id="loginmyForm" method="post">
<input class="input input_auth" type="text"  name="loginemail" id="loginemail" placeholder="E-mail" required />
<span id="loginError_username" class="error error-opacit"></span>

<input class="input input_auth" type="password" name="loginpassword" id="loginpassword" placeholder="Password" required />
<span id="loginError_password" class="error error-opacit"></span>
<input type="hidden" name="source" value="login" id="source">
    
<button class="btn pulse input_auth" type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="loginSubmitFormData();" value="Submit">Login</button>

<div class="forgot-password">
    <a id="forgotPass" href="#" class="link-btn open-modal" data-openModal="modal-recovery">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
```

**Here is jquery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loginSubmitFormData() {
    var loginemail = $("#loginemail").val();
    var loginpassword = $("#loginpassword").val();
    var source = $("#source").val();
    $.post("authlogin.php", { loginemail: loginemail, loginpassword: loginpassword },
       function(data) {
         $('#loginresults').html(data);
         $('#loginmyForm')[0].reset();
       });
}
</script>
```

**And here is the login authentication authlogin.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'config/info.php';

    // get the details from form 
    $email=$_POST['loginemail'];
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['loginpassword']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='".$email."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $Countrow = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($Countrow == 1) {
        $fetchrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
        $loginpassword = $fetchrow['password'];

        // Verify the password here
        if (password_verify($password, $loginpassword)) {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            //setcookie('username', $adminID, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $ActivityStmt = "INSERT INTO login_activity (`email`, `last_login`, `browser`, `os`, `ip_address`) VALUES('".$email."', '".$date."', '".$gen_userBrowser."', '".$gen_userOS."', '".$gen_userIP."')";
            $ActivityResult = mysqli_query($conn, $ActivityStmt);

            echo 'Login Successfully! <a href="account" style="color: green;">Click to proceed</a>';

            exit();
        }
        else{
            echo 'Incorrect Password';
            exit();
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'User does not exit';
        exit();
    }
    ?>
```

I have tried using

```
header('Location: account');
```

and

```
window.location.href = "account";
```

after the session is saved but none is working, please who can help me on how to get this done

Comment: could you print what the `console.log(data);` shows 
because window.location.href = "account"; will redirect you normlly

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this jQuery Code and PHP Code by replacing them in your code section, It will definitely work for you:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loginSubmitFormData() {
    var loginemail = $("#loginemail").val();
    var loginpassword = $("#loginpassword").val();
    var source = $("#source").val();
    $.post("authlogin.php", { loginemail: loginemail, loginpassword: loginpassword },
       function(data) {
         var data = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
         console.log(data);
         $('#loginresults').html(data.message);
         if(data.redirect_url){
            window.location.href = data.redirect_url;
         }
         $('#loginmyForm')[0].reset();
       });
}
</script>

<?php
    session_start();
    include 'config/info.php';

    // get the details from form 
    $email=$_POST['loginemail'];
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['loginpassword']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='".$email."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $Countrow = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($Countrow == 1) {
        $fetchrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
        $loginpassword = $fetchrow['password'];

        // Verify the password here
        if (password_verify($password, $loginpassword)) {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            //setcookie('username', $adminID, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $ActivityStmt = "INSERT INTO login_activity (`email`, `last_login`, `browser`, `os`, `ip_address`) VALUES('".$email."', '".$date."', '".$gen_userBrowser."', '".$gen_userOS."', '".$gen_userIP."')";
            $ActivityResult = mysqli_query($conn, $ActivityStmt);

            $message = 'Login Successfully!';
            
            $response = array(
                'message' => $message,
                'redirect_url' => 'https://www.example.com',
            );
            
            exit();
        }
        else{
            $message = 'Incorrect Password';
            $response = array(
                'message' => $message
            );
            exit();
        }
    }
    else{
        $message = 'User does not exit';
        $response = array(
            'message' => $message,
        );
        exit();
    }
    
    echo json_encode( $response);
    ?>
```

Comment: You can use code from above jquery and PHP section code, it will redirect properly on set url.